# Не получается подключить библиотеку к проекту в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, github

Пытаюсь подключить эту библиотеку к проекту.
https://github.com/aashari/mi-band-2
 Но она не выглядит как обычная. Там нет ни джарников ни ссылки для build.gradle.Каким образом мне добавить эту либу в проект?

Comment: Это не подключаемая  библиотека, а пример приложения, как работать с Mi band 2. Это не нужно добавлять в проект, это нужно посмотреть исходный код и делать у себя так же.

Comment: я добавил это в код и ему не хватает каких то библиотек

Comment: import id.aashari.code.miband2.Helpers.CustomBluetoothProfile;
import id.aashari.code.miband2.R;

Comment: это импорты классов (класс R вообще создается при сборке проекта автоматически), которые вы не должны копировать целиком, а взять их в качестве примера из репозитория и на их основе сделать свои.

Comment: import id.aashari.code.miband2.R; это ссылка на класс проекта с гитхаб. Вам нужно использовать импорт из пакета вашего проекта - import com.you.app.R;

id.aashari.code.miband2.Helpers.CustomBluetoothProfile соответственно тоже не импортируется потому что пакет неверный (судя по тому что вы написали). Так что всё зависит от того что именно вы сделали. Но похоже вы не до конца понимаете устройство пакетов и классов в java. И это не относится к android.

Answer (score 1):

1) [ссылка](https://github.com/aashari/mi-band-2) на репозиторий в котором лежит целый проект.

2) подключить для использования возможно только нужно уточнить что именно вам нужно из этого проекта

3) обычно если существует возможность подключения через gradle то сопсоб описывается в readme. [пример](https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/decoro)

в этом репозитории только [два класса](https://github.com/aashari/mi-band-2/tree/master/app/src/main/java/id/aashari/code/miband2). Если действительно необходимо переиспользовать код из этого проекта то можно выделить из него модуль app. Переименовть его (например в miband) и добавить к своему главному модулю и прописать этот модуль в settings.gradle корня проекта:

`include ':miband'`

добавить зависимость в build.gradle главного модуля

`compile project(':miband')`

В данном случае я бы просто скопировал эти два класса к себе в проект.

Comment: Трудно представить ситуацию, в которой в другом приложении понадобился бы целиком демонстрационный сэмпл .. эти классы не надо ни импортировать ни копировать - это пример.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Боюсь человек, который задал вопрос, не до конца понимает чего хочет. И что с этим делать.